# Twitter streaming api hangs

Tags: twitter

I was able to get this to run without any error being thrown however after it gets to the line "string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();" it just hangs.  I have a breakpoint on the next line and still nothing.  Am I not using this correctly?  This is in a windows forms application.  What do I need to do in order to parse this out? How do I grab the data while keeping the stream open?

My goal with this is to be able to grab tweets and sort them based on criteria TBD.

```
var oAuthToken = "****";
        var oAuthTokenSecret = "****";
        var oAuthConsumerKey = "****";
        var oAuthConsumerSecret = "****";

        var oAuthVersion = "1.0";
        var oAuthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";

        var oAuthNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oAuthTimeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        var resourceURL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json";
        var locations = "-180,-90,180,90";

        var baseFormat = "locations={6}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";
        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                        oAuthConsumerKey,
                        oAuthNonce,
                        oAuthSignatureMethod,
                        oAuthTimeStamp,
                        oAuthToken,
                        oAuthVersion,
                        Uri.EscapeDataString(locations)
                        );

        baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceURL), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerSecret),
                    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthTokenSecret));

        string oAuthSignature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oAuthSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthNonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthSignatureMethod),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthTimeStamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthToken),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthSignature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthVersion)
                        );

        //make the request

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var postBody = "locations=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(locations);
        resourceURL += "?" + postBody;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resourceURL);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        try
        {

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw (exception);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a streaming API, so it will stream infinitely. Hence if you are trying to read to the end of stream, it will block forever until you run out of memory or get disconnected due to network error etc.

You need to process the data while connected to the stream. If I were you I'd just use a client library (see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).